# Presenter setup with i3 and xrandr

Tags: linux, xrandr, i3-window-manager

I am in need of some `xrandr` magic, I guess:

I am using the i3 tiling window manager on a Linux notebook and am looking for a way to produce the following result:

On my **notebook screen** I'd like to have a window/split screen with my paper and some kind of windos/pane that allows me to see and control my presentation.

The presentation itself shout be output on the projector.

Can anybody think of a setup I might use?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, it is trivial to send an entire workspace to another monitor (first `xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto` and then move the workspace to the new screen). However, I would need something like: `xrandr --output HDMI1 --same-as <COORDINATES OF i3 WINDOW>'.
The coordinates could be obtained from the `i3-msg -t get_tree` command. There will be also be problems with scaling and resolution, I guess.

Comment: Could you then edit your question with a detailed description of what you've tried and the exact problems that hinder you from succeeding what you are trying to accomplish?